# Specify constraints in the CREATE clause in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to set the Quantity attribute to limit from 1 to 100.
Does anyone know why this code isn't working?

```
CREATE TABLE REQUEST (
  OrderID     VARCHAR2(4),
  ProductID   VARCHAR2(2),
  Quantity    INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT check_quantity CHECK((INTEGER > 0) AND (INTEGER < 101)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want `CHECK((Quantity > 0) AND (Quantity < 101))` ?

Equivalently, you could write `CHECK(Quantity BETWEEN 1 AND 100)`

Comment: o that right. haha thanks! by the way is there a difference between int and integer?

Comment: @Ronnie, Sorry, I don't know - I'm more of a SQL Server guy, and unlike your original question, that would be Oracle-specific...

Comment: @Ronnie: The actual Oracle data type is NUMBER -- INT, INTEGER, etc are accepted synonyms.  Ever database that I can think of that supports INT as a synonym for INTEGER.

Comment: if the problem request whole numbers from 1 to 100, should i use number or integer? since the scale is 0 if i put number(3)?